# Flask show return data on request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have some problems.
I am new to python and flask.

I am building an API that makes queries to a database, a separate application front end and back end. But problems have come to rescue the search result with the Flask.

Example:

The Following 'curl' command registers a new user with username 'miguel' and password 'python':

```
$ Curl -X POST -H -i "Content-Type: application / json 
'd' {"username":" miguel","password":"python"} 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users
```

**RETURN:**

> HTTP / 1.0 201 CREATED Content-Type: application / json
>   Content-Length: 27 Location: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users/1 Server:
>   Werkzeug / Python 0.9.4 / 2.7.3 Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 19:56:39 GMT { 
>   "username": "miguel"  }

---

Through doterminal we return the username, someone knows a way to retrieve and display the user's name on the front end.

Resaltar it should consider font end and back and running on different machines.

--------UPDATE-------

**BACKEND**

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')
    if username is None or password is None:
        abort(400)    # missing arguments
    if User.query.filter_by(username=username).first() is not None:
        abort(400)    # existing user
    user = User(username=username)
    user.hash_password(password)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return (jsonify({'username': user.username}), 201,
            {'Location': url_for('get_user', id=user.id, _external=True)})
```

**FRONTEND**

```
@home_blueprint.route('/cadastro', methods=['POST'])
def cadastro():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    if username and password:
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/users'
        payload = {'username': username,'password':password}
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

    else:
        return "ERRO"
    return "Create new user sucesso!"
```

Comment: you are already getting the response, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough.
You want the request to return to your browser.
Currently my code records only new users but does not display the return.

Comment: @JoselânioFerreiradeMorais: Your code maybe little helpful for us, and do you want to display the *return* message to user? How do you get the data?

Comment: @KevinGuan Thank you for your contribution. post edited (update show code)

Comment: @JoselânioFerreiradeMorais: Maybe change `return "Create new user sucesso!"` to `return r.text`?

Comment: Very good, resolved issue.
Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge @KevinGuan I spent all day trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(post my comment as an answer)</sub>

You could simply use `r.text` to get the `requests.post`'s retun data, from [the document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content):

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding guessed by Requests is used when you access `r.text`.

So just replace

```
return "Create new user sucesso!"
```

with

```
return r.text
```

In this case, `r.text` is `requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)` return data, was created by:

```
return (jsonify({'username': user.username}), 201,
        {'Location': url_for('get_user', id=user.id, _external=True)})
```